# Recommendation for thickening agent for use in basil seed drink, to prevent seeds from collecting at the bottom

Tags: drinks, thickening

I was wondering what might be a good choice for a flavorless and clear thickening/gelling agent for use in a home made basil seed drink.

I am trying to imitate the commercially available basil seed drink products which mention a 'gelling agent' of sorts in the ingredients list and as such have a higher viscosity than regular water, which allows the seeds to be suspended in the liquid rather than sink and collect at the bottom of the container.

I was hoping to find recipes and ingredients which would not have any adverse or notable effects on health or detract from the flavorless nature of the basil seeds themselves.

I would really appreciate any thoughts and recommendations.

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options - xanthan gum, guar gum, and plain old unflavored gelatin could all be used. You would need to experiment a bit to get the desired effect.

Comment: Thankyou, I am currently experimenting with a few options,and your response has set me on the right track. I am leaning towards gums which would be safe in larger quantities, as I have read that most gums have certain degrees of side effects and daily consumption limits. I am also looking into Gum Arabic (which sounds like an interesting choice since it is supposed to have certain health benefits), Gellan gum, and Psyllium husk as mentioned by @daniel

Comment: The options posted by others are also very helpful, yet this answer is selected as correct as it mentions the prospect of several options. Again thankyou very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I use [xanthan gum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xanthan_gum) to thicken dressing.  Not sure how it would work in a drink.

Comment: Thankyou, I am currently deciding between all the available options.  The gelling agent mentioned in the commercial basil seed drink is E418 - Gellan gum, which also seems like a popular choice by many. Thankyou again very much for your time and help, it is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try [psyllium husk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psyllium) - fairly neutral and free of calories.

Comment: Very interesting, thankyou for mentioning this, Psyllium husk might be a good alternative to the various gums used as thickening agents. It is readily available in most grocery stores in my country as it is used by many to aid in digestions, although i am looking into the daily consumption limit and reported side effects as I have become an avid drinker of the basil seed drink. Thankyou again very much for your help.